# [Centos6.5][Spectre] variant 2 not getting fixed

Tags: centos

My Guest os (CentOS 6.5 ,kernel version 2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64) is running in ESXI server (VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-6480324, 
    patch ESXi550-201709001.zip was applied ) .
I installed all the packages mentioned in https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2018-January/

The list of installed packages are

```
kernel-debug-devel-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.i686
kernel-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
kernel-doc-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.noarch
kernel-debug-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
kernel-devel-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
kernel-debug-devel-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
libreport-plugin-kerneloops-2.0.9-19.el6.centos.x86_64
abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.0.8-21.el6.centos.x86_64
dracut-kernel-004-409.el6_8.2.noarch
kernel-headers-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.noarch
kernel-abi-whitelists-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.noarch
dracut-004-409.el6_8.2.noarch
dracut-kernel-004-409.el6_8.2.noarch    
elfutils-libs-0.164-2.el6.x86_64
elfutils-0.164-2.el6.x86_64
elfutils-libelf-devel-0.164-2.el6.x86_64
elfutils-libelf-0.164-2.el6.x86_64
elfutils-devel-0.164-2.el6.x86_64
microcode_ctl-1.17-25.2.el6_9.x86_64
python-perf-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
perf-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
```

But /sys/kernel/debug/x86/ibrs_enabled is still set to 0 and if I execute

```
echo 2 > /sys/kernel/debug/x86/ibrs_enabled"
```

then we are getting the error

> "bash: echo: write error: No such device".

The content of `/sys/kernel/debug/x86/ibpb_enabled` is also `0`  and

```
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/x86/ibpb_enabled
```

throws the same error

> "bash: echo: write error: No such device" .

I used a tool https://raw.githubusercontent.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker/master/spectre-meltdown-checker.sh to 
    detect if meltdown and spectre got fixed . Spectre Variant 1 and Meltdown got fixed but not Variant 2 .

```
"CVE-2017-5715 [branch target injection] aka 'Spectre Variant 2'
* Mitigation 1
*   Hardware (CPU microcode) support for mitigation:  YES
*   Kernel support for IBRS:  YES
*   IBRS enabled for Kernel space:  NO
*   IBRS enabled for User space:  NO
* Mitigation 2
*   Kernel compiled with retpoline option:  NO
*   Kernel compiled with a retpoline-aware compiler:  NO
> STATUS:  VULNERABLE  (IBRS hardware + kernel support OR kernel with retpoline are needed to mitigate the vulnerability)"
```

Answer (score 1):

> But /sys/kernel/debug/x86/ibrs_enabled is still set to 0 and if I execute `echo 2 > /sys/kernel/debug/x86/ibrs_enabled` then we are getting the error
>
> > "bash: echo: write error: No such device" .
>
> The content of /sys/kernel/debug/x86/ibpb_enabled is also 0 and echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/x86/ibpb_enabled throws the error
>
> > "bash: echo: write error: No such device

On Centos 6 (unlike CentOS 7) to be able to write go those locations you need to mount the kernel debugfs

```
 mount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug
```

Comment: I had done it :)

Comment: @lain I tried on centos 7.4 but failed
#  echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/x86/ibpb_enabled
-bash: echo: write error: No such device
for : # cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

Answer (score 0):

I have several CentOS 6.x and CentOS 7 Hosts.

My hosts run on VMWare ESX hosts therefore they needed patching to get the latest cpu features like ibrs and spec_ctrl.

After patching the hosts all VM's needed an upgrade to VMWare hardware version >= 9.

Finally I installed the new kernels provided by CentOS which make use of mitigtaion features added by the microcode update.

As VMWare states you need to power cycle every VM to get the new CPU features ready.

Before the power cycle (reboots) it was impossible to execute echo 2 > /sys/kernel/debug/x86/ibrs_enabled

After power cycling it worked like a charm and all 3 Spectre variants got mitigated on all my CentOS VM's.
I have created an cron job that sets ibrs_enabled to 2 on every reboot as this setting wont persist, though the CentOS kernel sets it to 1 by default if new features provided by microcode are available.